# 'Module' not callable with numba's jit compiler

Tags: python, compiler-errors, jit, numba

I'm trying to compile my python code using the jit compiler from numba. However, I keep getting the 'module' not callable error. How do I correctly call this decorator?. I first install numba and then import it as jit. See the code below.

```
!conda install -y numba
import numba as jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def calltree_explicit(S0, K, T, r, sigma, delta, N):
    deltaT = T/float(N)
    u = np.exp(sigma * np.sqrt(deltaT))
    d = 1/u
    p = (np.exp((r-delta)*deltaT) - d)/(u-d)   
    pstar = np.exp(-(r-delta)*deltaT)*p*u
    a = np.ceil(N/2+np.log(K/S0)/(2*np.log(u)))
    return np.exp(-delta*T)*S0*binom.sf(a-1, N, pstar)-binom.sf(a-1, N, 
    p)*np.exp(-r*T)*K
```

This should compile my code to make it faster

But I receive the

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-3cc5b3c83b9f> in <module>()
----> 1 @jit(nopython=True)
      2 def calltree_explicit(S0, K, T, r, sigma, delta, N):
      3     deltaT = T/float(N)
      4     u = np.exp(sigma * np.sqrt(deltaT))
      5     d = 1/u

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

A TypeError: 'module' object is not callable means you're trying to use something like a function when it's not actually a function or a method.You have problem with numba import, maybe you should try

```
from numba import jit
```

Comment: In that case I receive the error: ImportError: cannot import name internal_prange

Comment: @M.Birk Works fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04.